# How to redirect a web service?

Tags: web-services, redirect

I have a web service which performs the submission of a small amount of data.  It provides a synchronous request response service for my clients.  This is working well.  I have a new requirement to also support the submission of a much larger amount of the same data; about 10,000 times more data volume.  Naturally the larger data will be an asynchronous service for my clients.

The infrastructure I use for the small amount of data cannot support both types of service; the large volume submissions will kill the responsiveness of my small volume submissions.

What I would like to do is be flexible with my deployment and make life simple for the people developing the client software which submits the data.  I have been looking for a standards based way to do this:
- client calls my data submission web service
- server determines the amount of data being submitted
- if data is too big the server responds to the client with a different uri.  The uri is for client to do the submission i.e. Redirect the client to bigger infrastructure
- client calls the different uri and gets service

I've done some searching and the general response is that this isn't something that is done in web services.  I don't understand why.  This seems like a reasonable requirement that is probably also true for clustered server scenario's.

Does anyone know if there are standards which cover this?  If not, is there a better way?

A subtlety in my case is that I want all the traffic to flow differently for the large submission so I can't simply front end my infrastructure with a web service content aware proxy server.  I need to push the web service call to a totally different place; much like a HTTP redirect.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the large volume submission service located on a different physical box?

Comment: Yes, the server/s that will handle the large volume submission are physically different.  They are totally different software stacks as well.

Comment: Would a HTTP 303 redirect response work for the web service redirect?